# matrix condition inside the while loop

Tags: r

Consider the following toy example:

```
set.seed(10)
(n <- sample(5,size=1))
(d <- matrix(sample(1:100, size = n), ncol=1))
(g <- matrix(sample(1:10, size = n), ncol=1))
i <-1

while(d>g){
  cat( "iteration" , i,"\n")
  g <- g+1
  i <- i + 1
}
g

Warning messages:
1: In while (d > g) { :
   the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Here `d` and `g` both are column vector. `R` is checking only the first element. As soon as the first element of `g` is greater than or equal to `d`, the loop terminates. But my intention is to execute the loop until each element of `g` is greater than or equal to `d`. If I would know the object `n` beforehand, I would write the condition inside the while loop as `(d[1]>g[1] &d[2]>g[2] &d[3]>g[3])`. But I don't know `n` beforehand. How can I do this?

Comment: `while (any(d > g)) {...}`?

Comment: @r2evans Writing `while (all(d>g))` gives the values of `g` at the end of loop (9,10,8); when d=(9,74,76). The last 2 elements of `d` are still greater than the last 2 elements of `g`.

Comment: `any`, not `all` (I updated it seconds after commenting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you need `any`:

```r
set.seed(10)
(n <- sample(5,size=1))
# [1] 3
(d <- matrix(sample(1:100, size = n), ncol=1))
#      [,1]
# [1,]   31
# [2,]   43
# [3,]   68
(g <- matrix(sample(1:10, size = n), ncol=1))
#      [,1]
# [1,]    1
# [2,]    3
# [3,]    9
i <- 1

while (any(d>g)) { g <- g+1; i <- i+1; }
i
# [1] 60
g
#      [,1]
# [1,]   60
# [2,]   62
# [3,]   68
```

I think trying to do this iteratively is unnecessary, though.

```r
set.seed(10)
n <- sample(5,size=1)
d <- matrix(sample(1:100, size = n), ncol=1)
g <- matrix(sample(1:10, size = n), ncol=1)
(i <- max(d - g) + 1)
# [1] 60
g <- g + i - 1
g
#      [,1]
# [1,]   60
# [2,]   62
# [3,]   68
```

Comment: Actually, I am using the concept in another task where I need to compare each element of two vector in while loop. Thanks.